# What's wrong with the Second Activity Java code?

Tags: java, android, layout, manifest

I am trying to design the app that has 3 buttons on the main screen; when the user presses on the first two buttons it plays the different music located in the raw folder. The third button on the main screen should drive the user to the next screen which also has 2 buttons.

I tried to run my app on the emulator. It plays the music on first two buttons of the main screen, and when I click on the third (Next) button it takes the user to the next screen. However, when I click on 1st or 2nd button of the Second Screen. It says "Unfortunately your app has stopped". I don't now what's wrong with my SecondActivity.Java code .

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Below is my MAIN and Second class JAVA code. I did declare my second Activity in manifest.xml file.

Main Activity Java Code..

```
    import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;




public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    private MediaPlayer mp;

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
      findViewById(R.id.button_1).setOnClickListener(this);
      findViewById(R.id.button_2).setOnClickListener(this);
      findViewById(R.id.button_3).setOnClickListener(this);
   }
   public void onClick(View v) {   
       int resId=1;
      switch (v.getId()) {
      case R.id.button_1: resId = R.raw.button_1; break;
      case R.id.button_2: resId = R.raw.button_2; break;
      case R.id.button_3:
         startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class));
         return;

      }
   // Release any resources from previous MediaPlayer
      if (mp != null) {   
          mp.release(); 
      }   
   // Create a new MediaPlayer to play this sound
      mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, resId); 
      mp.start();
   }
}
```

SecondActivity.Java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;




public class SecondActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    private MediaPlayer mp;



   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
      setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
      findViewById(R.id.button_4).setOnClickListener(this);
      findViewById(R.id.button_5).setOnClickListener(this);
   }
   public void onClick(View v) {
        int resId = 1;
        // Release any resources from previous MediaPlayer
        if (mp != null) {               
            mp.release();   
        }

        // Create a new MediaPlayer to play this sound
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, resId); 
        mp.start();

        switch (v.getId()) {
          case R.id.button_4: resId = R.raw.button_4; break;
          case R.id.button_5: resId = R.raw.button_5; break;
        }
       }
    }
```

Comment: @AlexBalo...I have attached my logcat errors..I am totally new to Android So  I have no idea... If possible can you please post the code for the second screen ...It will be a great help ..

Comment: You are creating the mediaplayer with an resId = 1, I think here is the problem, this resource does not exist in Your raw-folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code should like this..
remove

```
 mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, resId); 
        mp.start();
```

> before  switch statement

```
    switch (v.getId()) {
      case R.id.button_4:
          resId = R.raw.button_4; 
          mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, resId); 
          mp.start();
          break;
      case R.id.button_5:
      resId = R.raw.button_5;
      mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, resId); 
      mp.start(); 
      break;
    }
```

Comment: I tried d code suggested by PedroHawk.. However, the music from the previous screen... Doesn't stop.. How can I fix that ?

Comment: before move second activity use  mo.pause() with current location pointer of mp3 song and then use mp.resume() with that location pointer

Answer (score 1):

on your second activity, create your mediapPlayer **AFTER** switch case. On your way, he will try to reproduce something that still doesn't exist:

```
 @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
      setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
      findViewById(R.id.button_4).setOnClickListener(this);
      findViewById(R.id.button_5).setOnClickListener(this);
   }
   public void onClick(View v) {
        int resId = 1;


        switch (v.getId()) {
          case R.id.button_4: resId = R.raw.button_4; break;
          case R.id.button_5: resId = R.raw.button_5; break;
        }

        // Release any resources from previous MediaPlayer
        if (mp != null) {               
            mp.release();   
        }

        // Create a new MediaPlayer to play this sound
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, resId); 
        mp.start();
       }
    }
```

**UPDATE:**
Execute the mp.release() before any action on your onclick():

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    private MediaPlayer mp;

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
      findViewById(R.id.button_1).setOnClickListener(this);
      findViewById(R.id.button_2).setOnClickListener(this);
      findViewById(R.id.button_3).setOnClickListener(this);
   }
   public void onClick(View v) {   
       int resId=1;

   // Release any resources from previous MediaPlayer
      if (mp != null) {   
          mp.release(); 
      } 

      switch (v.getId()) {
      case R.id.button_1: resId = R.raw.button_1; break;
      case R.id.button_2: resId = R.raw.button_2; break;
      case R.id.button_3:
         startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class));
         break;

      }

   // Create a new MediaPlayer to play this sound
      mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, resId); 
      mp.start();
   }
}
```

Comment: your logcat is very explicit: `Resources$NotFoundException` at line 34 of your secondActivity.

Comment: user3856054 if you feel your question is solved, close this topic. keep programing

Comment: I tried your code .. and It worked.. However, the music from the previous (main) screen .. does not stop.. How can I fix that ?

Comment: before to start secondactivity, you must release firstactivity mediaPlayer with release() method. try it

Comment: FIRST: `if (mp != null) { mp.release(); }` RIGHT NEXT:  `startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class));` In other way, you will start activity and you wont stop MediaPlayer

Comment: Ok.. my friend.. I change my codes for the main activity as follows.. but the songs on main screen are not playing..       switch (v.getId()) {
      case R.id.button_1: resId = R.raw.button_1; break;
      case R.id.button_2: resId = R.raw.button_2; break;
      case R.id.button_3:
       if (mp != null) { mp.release(); } startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class));
         return;

      }
   // Release any resources from previous MediaPlayer
      if (mp != null) {   
       mp.release(); 
      }   
   
   }
}

Comment: Thumps Up ...for my friend  PedroHawk....The code really worked...Thanks a ton...

Comment: I got one more problem ..with my app please follow the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24871473/how-to-stop-second-screen-music-when-user-presses-the-back-button?lq=1

Answer (score 0):

The error says the following:

```
Resources not found with id of 0x01
```

meaning the problem is this:

```
int resId = 1;
mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, resId);
```

That is a resource ID that does not exist.

If you have these files in your /res/raw folder, then you should use the `R.raw.xyz` ID.

Although I guess the problem really is just that the

```
   // Create a new MediaPlayer to play this sound
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, resId); 
    mp.start();

    switch (v.getId()) {
      case R.id.button_4: resId = R.raw.button_4; break;
      case R.id.button_5: resId = R.raw.button_5; break;
    }
   }
```

Are mixed up instead of

```
    switch (v.getId()) {
      case R.id.button_4: resId = R.raw.button_4; break;
      case R.id.button_5: resId = R.raw.button_5; break;
    }
   }

   // Create a new MediaPlayer to play this sound
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, resId); 
    mp.start();
```

Comment: whenever.. I try to change..int resId = 1 --to-- int resId... It gives me an error  at "mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, resId)"... saying I have to initialize it...That's why I put "int resId = 1 "

Comment: well, yes, but that resId doesn't exist. give it a specific R.raw.somethingaudio