# How to stop Second Screen music when user presses the back button?

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

I asked [this  question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24867102/whats-wrong-with-the-second-activity-java-code) a couple of hours ago and I did made some changes in my code as suggested by stack overflow users. However, One more problem started to emerge. The problem is that whenever, I try to go back from the second Screen to the main screen ..The music from second screen doesn't stop.

[ "I am trying to design the app that has 3 buttons on the main screen; when the user presses on the first two buttons it plays the different music located in the raw folder. The third button on the main screen should drive the user to the next screen which also has 2 buttons.

I tried to run my app on the emulator. It plays the music on first two buttons of the main screen, and when I click on the third (Next) button it takes the user to the next screen. However, when I click on 1st or 2nd button of the Second Screen. It says "Unfortunately your app has stopped". I don't now what's wrong with my SecondActivity.Java code .

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Below is my MAIN and Second class JAVA code. I did declare my second Activity in manifest.xml file." ]

Second Activity.Java

```
    import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;




public class SecondActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    private MediaPlayer mp;


    @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
          setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
          findViewById(R.id.button_4).setOnClickListener(this);
          findViewById(R.id.button_5).setOnClickListener(this);
       }
       public void onClick(View v) {
            int resId = 1;


            switch (v.getId()) {
              case R.id.button_4: resId = R.raw.button_4; break;
              case R.id.button_5: resId = R.raw.button_5; break;
            }

            // Release any resources from previous MediaPlayer
            if (mp != null) {               
                mp.release();   
            }

            // Create a new MediaPlayer to play this sound
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, resId); 
            mp.start();
           }
        }
```

Logcat errors..

```
07-21 18:06:14.898: E/BinaryDictionaryGetter(157): Could not find a dictionary pack
07-21 18:06:22.518: E/SoundPool(89): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
07-21 18:06:22.518: E/SoundPool(89): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
07-21 18:06:22.518: E/SoundPool(89): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
07-21 18:06:22.518: E/SoundPool(89): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
07-21 18:06:22.518: E/SoundPool(89): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
07-21 18:06:22.698: E/SoundPool(89): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
07-21 18:06:22.698: E/SoundPool(89): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
07-21 18:06:22.698: E/SoundPool(89): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
07-21 18:06:22.698: E/SoundPool(89): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
07-21 18:06:42.096: E/SurfaceTexture(35): [<pid_66>] dequeueBuffer: SurfaceTexture has been abandoned!
07-21 18:06:47.276: E/ActivityManager(89): ANR in com.android.settings
07-21 18:06:47.276: E/ActivityManager(89): Reason: Broadcast of Intent { act=android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED flg=0x10 cmp=com.android.settings/.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider }
07-21 18:06:47.276: E/ActivityManager(89): Load: 6.43 / 1.85 / 0.64
07-21 18:06:47.276: E/ActivityManager(89): CPU usage from 47ms to 23826ms later:
07-21 18:06:47.276: E/ActivityManager(89):   30% 35/surfaceflinger: 27% user + 2.6% kernel / faults: 1542 minor
07-21 18:06:47.276: E/ActivityManager(89):   21% 89/system_server: 15% user + 5.2% kernel / faults: 2206 minor 1 major
07-21 18:06:47.276: E/ActivityManager(89):   16% 44/adbd: 2% user + 14% kernel / faults: 32 minor
07-21 18:06:47.276: E/ActivityManager(89):   7.2% 143/com.android.systemui: 5.4% user + 1.7% kernel / faults: 3963 minor 3 major
07-21 18:06:47.276: E/ActivityManager(89):   7.1% 191/com.android.launcher: 6.3% user + 0.8% kernel / faults: 834 minor 2 major
07-21 18:06:47.276: E/ActivityManager(89):   4.6% 176/zygote: 3.4% user + 1.2% kernel / faults: 610 minor 2 major
07-21 18:06:47.276: E/ActivityManager(89):   4.4% 231/android.process.acore: 3.5% user + 0.9% kernel / faults: 2025 minor 1 major
07-21 18:06:47.276: E/ActivityManager(89):   0.3% 212/com.android.settings: 0% user + 0.2% kernel / faults: 377 minor
07-21 18:06:47.276: E/ActivityManager(89):   0.1% 37/mediaserver: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 6 minor
07-21 18:06:47.276: E/ActivityManager(89):   0.1% 29/servicemanager: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
07-21 18:06:47.276: E/ActivityManager(89):   0% 34/rild: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 2 minor
07-21 18:06:47.276: E/ActivityManager(89):  +0% 257/sh: 0% user + 0% kernel
07-21 18:06:47.276: E/ActivityManager(89):  +0% 260/logcat: 0% user + 0% kernel
07-21 18:06:47.276: E/ActivityManager(89): 100% TOTAL: 70% user + 27% kernel + 0.2% irq + 1.9% softirq
07-21 18:06:47.276: E/ActivityManager(89): CPU usage from 21060ms to 22770ms later:
07-21 18:06:47.276: E/ActivityManager(89):   36% 89/system_server: 22% user + 13% kernel / faults: 236 minor
07-21 18:06:47.276: E/ActivityManager(89):     8.8% 104/ActivityManager: 3.6% user + 5.1% kernel
07-21 18:06:47.276: E/ActivityManager(89):     8% 255/Error dump: sys: 5.8% user + 2.2% kernel
07-21 18:06:47.276: E/ActivityManager(89):     6.6% 96/Compiler: 5.1% user + 1.4% kernel
07-21 18:06:47.276: E/ActivityManager(89):     2.2% 118/WindowManagerPo: 2.2% user + 0% kernel
07-21 18:06:47.276: E/ActivityManager(89):     1.4% 265/Binder Thread #: 0.7% user + 0.7% kernel
07-21 18:06:47.276: E/ActivityManager(89):     0.7% 264/Binder Thread #: 0% user + 0.7% kernel
07-21 18:06:47.276: E/ActivityManager(89):   29% 35/surfaceflinger: 26% user + 3.5% kernel / faults: 383 minor
07-21 18:06:47.276: E/ActivityManager(89):     26% 63/SurfaceFlinger: 23% user + 3.5% kernel
07-21 18:06:47.276: E/ActivityManager(89):     0.7% 254/Binder Thread #: 0% user + 0.7% kernel
07-21 18:06:47.276: E/ActivityManager(89):   25% 44/adbd: 2.2% user + 23% kernel
07-21 18:06:47.276: E/ActivityManager(89):     9.1% 44/adbd: 0% user + 9.1% kernel
07-21 18:06:47.276: E/ActivityManager(89):     9.1% 79/adbd: 3.8% user + 5.3% kernel
07-21 18:06:47.276: E/ActivityManager(89):     9.1% 249/adbd: 0% user + 9.1% kernel
07-21 18:06:47.276: E/ActivityManager(89):     8.3% 78/adbd: 0% user + 8.3% kernel
07-21 18:06:47.276: E/ActivityManager(89):   9.5% 143/com.android.systemui: 3.9% user + 5.5% kernel / faults: 403 minor
07-21 18:06:47.276: E/ActivityManager(89):     7.9% 143/ndroid.systemui: 3.1% user + 4.7% kernel
07-21 18:06:47.276: E/ActivityManager(89):     1.5% 150/Compiler: 1.5% user + 0% kernel
07-21 18:06:47.276: E/ActivityManager(89):   2.6% 191/com.android.launcher: 1.7% user + 0.8% kernel / faults: 47 minor
07-21 18:06:47.276: E/ActivityManager(89):     2.6% 191/ndroid.launcher: 1.7% user + 0.8% kernel
07-21 18:06:47.276: E/ActivityManager(89):     0.8% 203/Compiler: 0.8% user + 0% kernel
07-21 18:06:47.276: E/ActivityManager(89):     0.8% 229/launcher-loader: 0.8% user + 0% kernel
07-21 18:06:47.276: E/ActivityManager(89):   0.8% 212/com.android.settings: 0.8% user + 0% kernel / faults: 3 minor
07-21 18:06:47.276: E/ActivityManager(89): 100% TOTAL: 56% user + 41% kernel + 1.7% softirq
07-21 18:07:00.696: A/NetworkStats(89): problem reading network stats
07-21 18:07:00.696: A/NetworkStats(89): java.lang.IllegalStateException: problem parsing line: null
07-21 18:07:00.696: A/NetworkStats(89):     at com.android.internal.net.NetworkStatsFactory.readNetworkStatsDetail(NetworkStatsFactory.java:313)
07-21 18:07:00.696: A/NetworkStats(89):     at com.android.server.NetworkManagementService.getNetworkStatsUidDetail(NetworkManagementService.java:1271)
07-21 18:07:00.696: A/NetworkStats(89):     at com.android.server.net.NetworkStatsService.performPollLocked(NetworkStatsService.java:810)
07-21 18:07:00.696: A/NetworkStats(89):     at com.android.server.net.NetworkStatsService.updateIfacesLocked(NetworkStatsService.java:721)
07-21 18:07:00.696: A/NetworkStats(89):     at com.android.server.net.NetworkStatsService.updateIfaces(NetworkStatsService.java:699)
07-21 18:07:00.696: A/NetworkStats(89):     at com.android.server.net.NetworkStatsService.access$000(NetworkStatsService.java:128)
07-21 18:07:00.696: A/NetworkStats(89):     at com.android.server.net.NetworkStatsService$8.handleMessage(NetworkStatsService.java:1546)
07-21 18:07:00.696: A/NetworkStats(89):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
07-21 18:07:00.696: A/NetworkStats(89):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-21 18:07:00.696: A/NetworkStats(89):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
07-21 18:07:00.696: A/NetworkStats(89): Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /proc/net/xt_qtaguid/stats: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
07-21 18:07:00.696: A/NetworkStats(89):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:406)
07-21 18:07:00.696: A/NetworkStats(89):     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78)
07-21 18:07:00.696: A/NetworkStats(89):     at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:42)
07-21 18:07:00.696: A/NetworkStats(89):     at com.android.internal.net.NetworkStatsFactory.readNetworkStatsDetail(NetworkStatsFactory.java:272)
07-21 18:07:00.696: A/NetworkStats(89):     ... 9 more
07-21 18:07:00.696: A/NetworkStats(89): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
07-21 18:07:00.696: A/NetworkStats(89):     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
07-21 18:07:00.696: A/NetworkStats(89):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:98)
07-21 18:07:00.696: A/NetworkStats(89):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:390)
07-21 18:07:00.696: A/NetworkStats(89):     ... 12 more
07-21 18:07:14.576: E/ActivityManager(89): Start proc android.process.media for content provider com.android.providers.downloads/.DownloadProvider: pid=317 uid=10008 gids={1015, 1023, 1024, 1006, 2001, 3003, 3007}Load: 8.1 / 2.6 / 0.92
07-21 18:07:14.576: E/ActivityManager(89): CPU usage from 574ms to -15561ms ago:
07-21 18:07:14.576: E/ActivityManager(89):   34% 44/adbd: 6.1% user + 28% kernel
07-21 18:07:14.576: E/ActivityManager(89):   28% 89/system_server: 21% user + 7.6% kernel / faults: 1350 minor
07-21 18:07:14.576: E/ActivityManager(89):   7.8% 272/com.android.contacts: 5.2% user + 2.6% kernel / faults: 3192 minor 16 major
07-21 18:07:14.576: E/ActivityManager(89):   7.1% 176/zygote: 5.2% user + 1.9% kernel / faults: 674 minor
07-21 18:07:14.576: E/ActivityManager(89):   4.3% 231/android.process.acore: 3.8% user + 0.4% kernel / faults: 213 minor
07-21 18:07:14.576: E/ActivityManager(89):   3% 36/zygote: 2.6% user + 0.3% kernel / faults: 349 minor
07-21 18:07:14.576: E/ActivityManager(89):   0.9% 143/com.android.systemui: 0.7% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 70 minor
07-21 18:07:14.576: E/ActivityManager(89):   0.4% 157/com.android.inputmethod.latin: 0.3% user + 0% kernel / faults: 373 minor
07-21 18:07:14.576: E/ActivityManager(89):   0.1% 260/logcat: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
07-21 18:07:14.576: E/ActivityManager(89):   0.1% 29/servicemanager: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
07-21 18:07:14.576: E/ActivityManager(89):   0.1% 34/rild: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
07-21 18:07:14.576: E/ActivityManager(89):   0% 1//init: 0% user + 0% kernel
07-21 18:07:14.576: E/ActivityManager(89):   0% 35/surfaceflinger: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 9 minor
07-21 18:07:14.576: E/ActivityManager(89):  +0% 304/com.android.providers.calendar: 0% user + 0% kernel
07-21 18:07:14.576: E/ActivityManager(89):  +0% 317/android.process.media: 0% user + 0% kernel
07-21 18:07:14.576: E/ActivityManager(89): 100% TOTAL: 53% user + 41% kernel + 0.5% irq + 4.6% softirq
07-21 18:07:14.576: E/ActivityManager(89): CPU usage from 12740ms to 14418ms later with 102% awake:
07-21 18:07:14.576: E/ActivityManager(89):   38% 44/adbd: 10% user + 28% kernel
07-21 18:07:14.576: E/ActivityManager(89):     11% 44/adbd: 3.7% user + 8.1% kernel
07-21 18:07:14.576: E/ActivityManager(89):     11% 78/adbd: 4.3% user + 6.8% kernel
07-21 18:07:14.576: E/ActivityManager(89):     11% 79/adbd: 4.3% user + 6.8% kernel
07-21 18:07:14.576: E/ActivityManager(89):     11% 249/adbd: 0% user + 11% kernel
07-21 18:07:14.576: E/ActivityManager(89):   32% 89/system_server: 26% user + 6.1% kernel / faults: 40 minor
07-21 18:07:14.576: E/ActivityManager(89):     12% 104/ActivityManager: 8.5% user + 3.6% kernel
07-21 18:07:14.576: E/ActivityManager(89):     12% 287/Binder Thread #: 12% user + 0% kernel
07-21 18:07:14.576: E/ActivityManager(89):     3% 91/GC: 1.8% user + 1.2% kernel
07-21 18:07:14.576: E/ActivityManager(89):     0.6% 96/Compiler: 0.6% user + 0% kernel
07-21 18:07:14.576: E/ActivityManager(89):     0.6% 102/SensorService: 0% user + 0.6% kernel
07-21 18:07:14.576: E/ActivityManager(89):     0.6% 121/er$SensorThread: 0.6% user + 0% kernel
07-21 18:07:14.576: E/ActivityManager(89):     0.6% 264/Binder Thread #: 0.6% user + 0% kernel
07-21 18:07:14.576: E/ActivityManager(89):   13% 36/zygote: 13% user + 0% kernel / faults: 47 minor
07-21 18:07:14.576: E/ActivityManager(89):     10% 36/zygote: 10% user + 0% kernel
07-21 18:07:14.576: E/ActivityManager(89):   8.5% 304/com.android.providers.calendar: 6.2% user + 2.3% kernel / faults: 103 minor
07-21 18:07:14.576: E/ActivityManager(89):     6.2% 304/viders.calendar: 4.6% user + 1.5% kernel
07-21 18:07:14.576: E/ActivityManager(89):     3.1% 311/Compiler: 1.5% user + 1.5% kernel
07-21 18:07:14.576: E/ActivityManager(89):   0.7% 231/android.process.acore: 0% user + 0.7% kernel / faults: 2 minor
07-21 18:07:14.576: E/ActivityManager(89):     0.7% 285/ContactsProvide: 0.7% user + 0% kernel
07-21 18:07:14.576: E/ActivityManager(89):   0.7% 317/<pre-initialized>: 0.7% user + 0% kernel / faults: 33 minor
07-21 18:07:14.576: E/ActivityManager(89): 100% TOTAL: 60% user + 34% kernel + 4.9% softirq
07-21 18:07:16.376: E/DefaultVoicemailNotifier(272): No voicemails to notify about: clear the notification.
07-21 18:07:23.277: A/NetworkStats(89): problem reading network stats
07-21 18:07:23.277: A/NetworkStats(89): java.lang.IllegalStateException: problem parsing line: null
07-21 18:07:23.277: A/NetworkStats(89):     at com.android.internal.net.NetworkStatsFactory.readNetworkStatsDetail(NetworkStatsFactory.java:313)
07-21 18:07:23.277: A/NetworkStats(89):     at com.android.server.NetworkManagementService.getNetworkStatsUidDetail(NetworkManagementService.java:1271)
07-21 18:07:23.277: A/NetworkStats(89):     at com.android.server.net.NetworkStatsService.performPollLocked(NetworkStatsService.java:810)
07-21 18:07:23.277: A/NetworkStats(89):     at com.android.server.net.NetworkStatsService.updateIfacesLocked(NetworkStatsService.java:721)
07-21 18:07:23.277: A/NetworkStats(89):     at com.android.server.net.NetworkStatsService.updateIfaces(NetworkStatsService.java:699)
07-21 18:07:23.277: A/NetworkStats(89):     at com.android.server.net.NetworkStatsService.access$000(NetworkStatsService.java:128)
07-21 18:07:23.277: A/NetworkStats(89):     at com.android.server.net.NetworkStatsService$1.onReceive(NetworkStatsService.java:589)
07-21 18:07:23.277: A/NetworkStats(89):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:728)
07-21 18:07:23.277: A/NetworkStats(89):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
07-21 18:07:23.277: A/NetworkStats(89):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-21 18:07:23.277: A/NetworkStats(89):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-21 18:07:23.277: A/NetworkStats(89):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
07-21 18:07:23.277: A/NetworkStats(89): Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /proc/net/xt_qtaguid/stats: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
07-21 18:07:23.277: A/NetworkStats(89):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:406)
07-21 18:07:23.277: A/NetworkStats(89):     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78)
07-21 18:07:23.277: A/NetworkStats(89):     at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:42)
07-21 18:07:23.277: A/NetworkStats(89):     at com.android.internal.net.NetworkStatsFactory.readNetworkStatsDetail(NetworkStatsFactory.java:272)
07-21 18:07:23.277: A/NetworkStats(89):     ... 11 more
07-21 18:07:23.277: A/NetworkStats(89): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
07-21 18:07:23.277: A/NetworkStats(89):     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
07-21 18:07:23.277: A/NetworkStats(89):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:98)
07-21 18:07:23.277: A/NetworkStats(89):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:390)
07-21 18:07:23.277: A/NetworkStats(89):     ... 14 more
07-21 18:07:28.996: E/ActivityThread(358): Failed to find provider info for com.android.inputmethod.latin.dictionarypack
07-21 18:07:29.116: E/BinaryDictionaryGetter(358): Could not find a dictionary pack
07-21 18:07:49.386: E/ActivityManager(89): Start proc com.android.defcontainer for service com.android.defcontainer/.DefaultContainerService: pid=476 uid=10025 gids={1015, 2001}Load: 12.23 / 4.22 / 1.52
07-21 18:07:49.386: E/ActivityManager(89): CPU usage from 1ms to 6936ms later:
07-21 18:07:49.386: E/ActivityManager(89):   32% 89/system_server: 20% user + 11% kernel / faults: 528 minor 1 major
07-21 18:07:49.386: E/ActivityManager(89):   20% 348/procrank: 7.2% user + 13% kernel / faults: 17 minor
07-21 18:07:49.386: E/ActivityManager(89):   19% 445/app_process: 16% user + 2.4% kernel / faults: 1896 minor 1 major
07-21 18:07:49.386: E/ActivityManager(89):   2% 402/com.android.email: 1.4% user + 0.5% kernel / faults: 50 minor
07-21 18:07:49.386: E/ActivityManager(89):   1.2% 44/adbd: 0% user + 1.2% kernel / faults: 1 minor
07-21 18:07:49.386: E/ActivityManager(89):   1.2% 143/com.android.systemui: 0.8% user + 0.4% kernel / faults: 33 minor
07-21 18:07:49.386: E/ActivityManager(89):   1.1% 176/zygote: 0.4% user + 0.7% kernel / faults: 64 minor
07-21 18:07:49.386: E/ActivityManager(89):   0.7% 36/zygote: 0.1% user + 0.5% kernel / faults: 150 minor
07-21 18:07:49.386: E/ActivityManager(89):   0.7% 317/android.process.media: 0.4% user + 0.2% kernel / faults: 56 minor
07-21 18:07:49.386: E/ActivityManager(89):   0.1% 260/logcat: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
07-21 18:07:49.386: E/ActivityManager(89):   0.1% 304/com.android.providers.calendar: 0.1% user + 0% kernel / faults: 14 minor
07-21 18:07:49.386: E/ActivityManager(89):   0% 35/surfaceflinger: 0% user + 0% kernel
07-21 18:07:49.386: E/ActivityManager(89):   0% 231/android.process.acore: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 11 minor
07-21 18:07:49.386: E/ActivityManager(89):   0% 334/com.android.deskclock: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 50 minor
07-21 18:07:49.386: E/ActivityManager(89):   0% 374/com.android.mms: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 4 minor
07-21 18:07:49.386: E/ActivityManager(89):   0.1% 425/com.android.exchange: 0.1% user + 0% kernel / faults: 12 minor
07-21 18:07:49.386: E/ActivityManager(89):  +0% 461/com.android.settings: 0% user + 0% kernel
07-21 18:07:49.386: E/ActivityManager(89):  +0% 476/com.android.defcontainer: 0% user + 0% kernel
07-21 18:07:49.386: E/ActivityManager(89):   0.-1% 272/com.android.contacts: 0.-1% user + 0% kernel
07-21 18:07:49.386: E/ActivityManager(89): 100% TOTAL: 60% user + 39% kernel + 0.1% softirq
07-21 18:07:49.386: E/ActivityManager(89): CPU usage from 5260ms to 6361ms later:
07-21 18:07:49.386: E/ActivityManager(89):   23% 461/com.android.settings: 7.2% user + 16% kernel / faults: 1888 minor
07-21 18:07:49.386: E/ActivityManager(89):     19% 461/ndroid.settings: 5.2% user + 14% kernel
07-21 18:07:49.386: E/ActivityManager(89):   21% 89/system_server: 8.6% user + 12% kernel / faults: 11 minor
07-21 18:07:49.386: E/ActivityManager(89):     20% 114/ScreenOffThread: 0% user + 20% kernel
07-21 18:07:49.386: E/ActivityManager(89):     13% 104/ActivityManager: 8.6% user + 4.8% kernel
07-21 18:07:49.386: E/ActivityManager(89):     0.9% 89/system_server: 0.9% user + 0% kernel
07-21 18:07:49.386: E/ActivityManager(89):     0.9% 96/Compiler: 0% user + 0.9% kernel
07-21 18:07:49.386: E/ActivityManager(89):   21% 348/procrank: 7.2% user + 14% kernel / faults: 2 minor
07-21 18:07:49.386: E/ActivityManager(89):   11% 445/app_process: 11% user + 0% kernel / faults: 126 minor
07-21 18:07:49.386: E/ActivityManager(89):     10% 445/app_process: 10% user + 0% kernel
07-21 18:07:49.386: E/ActivityManager(89):     3.1% 457/Compiler: 3.1% user + 0% kernel
07-21 18:07:49.386: E/ActivityManager(89):    +0% 474/Binder Thread #: 0% user + 0% kernel
07-21 18:07:49.386: E/ActivityManager(89):    +0% 475/Binder Thread #: 0% user + 0% kernel
07-21 18:07:49.386: E/ActivityManager(89):   4.3% 143/com.android.systemui: 4.3% user + 0% kernel / faults: 9 minor
07-21 18:07:49.386: E/ActivityManager(89):     3.2% 143/ndroid.systemui: 3.2% user + 0% kernel
07-21 18:07:49.386: E/ActivityManager(89):   0.9% 44/adbd: 0% user + 0.9% kernel
07-21 18:07:49.386: E/ActivityManager(89):     0.9% 44/adbd: 0% user + 0.9% kernel
07-21 18:07:49.386: E/ActivityManager(89):   1.1% 176/com.android.phone: 0% user + 1.1% kernel / faults: 12 minor
07-21 18:07:49.386: E/ActivityManager(89):   0.3% 304/com.android.providers.calendar: 0.3% user + 0% kernel / faults: 8 minor
07-21 18:07:49.386: E/ActivityManager(89):     0.3% 311/Compiler: 0% user + 0.3% kernel
07-21 18:07:49.386: E/ActivityManager(89): 100% TOTAL: 57% user + 42% kernel
: E/(): Device disconnected
```

Comment: Your logcat knows the problem. You need to check it and post it here if you don't understand it.

Comment: @ codeMagic.... Logcat error coming up in 5 min..

Comment: When posting, you want the smallest bit of code needed to start. So here, for example, the first class is most likely not needed to begin with since your issue is happening in the second class...just an fyi

Comment: @codeMagic...thanks for tip..I Have updated logcat errors with my post...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this stage, you should know something about **activity lifecycle**:

when you want to leave an activity, and in this case you want to stop music, you must implement `onPause()` method. Its when your activity is about to go off of your UI, and you want to stop all sounds playing, you should put something in your **ALL activities with mediaPlayer** like this:

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();  // Always call the superclass method first

    // Release any resources from previous MediaPlayer
        if (mp != null) {               
            mp.release();   
        }
}
```